# Enum values in Couchbase. string or integer?

Tags: couchbase, database, nosql

When storing enum like properties in couchbase, which is the preferred option and why ?

- are there any performance considerations ?
- how about code maintenance and re-factoring ?

should it be saved as:
{
  color : 'red'
}
or 
{
  color : 1
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> { color : 'red' } or { color : 1 }

Always do `color: red` in the database.

Reasons:

- When you add a new enum value you don't need to be careful of the 'index'
- Self documenting : there is no confusion what `red` means.

Also. The same should be done in your web API's.